# Any way to view VSCode "find in files" results organized by folder hierarchy?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm coming from Eclipse where searching for a string across files using ^h organizes the results by the folder in which they were found, like this:

[search results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Cg5A.png)

This is very handy, as folders can be collapsed and expanded to narrow the results.  Is there a similar capability (out of the box or via an extension) for vscode?

Comment: Also interested in this...
There is an open issue to get this feature implemented: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/20224

Answer (score 4):

VSCode 1.72 (Sept. 2022) should help, since [issue 20224](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/20224) is now fixed by [PR 161022](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/161022).
There is a new action "`View as Tree`" (`search.action.viewAsTree`).
This is available in [VSCode Insiders today](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/).

[Anil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/580724/anil) reports in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54133206/any-way-to-view-vscode-find-in-files-results-organized-by-folder-hierarchy/73827941#comment134264727_73827941):

> The settings value is `search.defaultViewMode`. See "[Default settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_default-settings)".

```
  // Controls the default search result view mode.
  //  - tree: Shows search results as a tree.
  //  - list: Shows search results as a list.
  "search.defaultViewMode": "list",
```

> ### Search Tree
>
> Shows the search results in a toggle-able tree.
>
> [image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/31675041/190530991-7f4b0501-4fc4-4ac6-b383-c248f876c049.png]
>
> And
>
> [image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/31675041/190531035-cb35e877-cf9c-4832-8acc-71988445d12b.png]

---

With [PR 173080](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/173080), VSCode 1.76 (Feb. 2023) introduces an extra state for search tree view collapse, as described in [issue 162812](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/162812).

> The default functionality should be the collapse the individual matches and only see the files/folders.
> Similar to how multi-root works

[image: https://camo.githubusercontent.com/9e563a6d56f8dd0eafb2f9da11a3b3756f97f80719155ca7504d9717a4d391ea/68747470733a2f2f692e6779617a6f2e636f6d2f66623136333363373063333337366562303866633935306530353039393332662e676966]

Comment: I was looking for this feature and just wanted to report the settings value is  `search.defaultViewMode`. Reference: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings.

Comment: @Anil Good catch, thank you for your feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

Now available in the new version of VSCode and can be done by using the new icon on the top of the search panel.

Comment: Thank you!  This icon here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7vyn.png

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no.

It's been 5 years since this feature has been suggested, but with no implementation yet despite the constant bumping of the issue and a lot of upvotes.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/20224

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31690898)