# How to see global search results as tree view instead of flat list in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I do a global search, results are shown as a flat list like the below:

[image]

How can I change it to **tree view** like how it's shown in the source control tab:

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54133206/any-way-to-view-vscode-find-in-files-results-organized-by-folder-hierarchy/73827941#73827941 - new `tree` view option coming in v1.72.